# Memory leak when using curl_easy_setopt

Tags: c, libcurl

I have the following code:

```
CURL *curl;

void http_init()
{
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl) return -1;
}

void http_send_message(char *msg_out, char **msg_in)
{
    CURLcode res;

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.133:8080/tawtaw");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "tawtaw");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "tawtaw");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC|CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
        .
        .
        .
   curl_easy_reset(curl); 
}

void http_exit()
{
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl); 
}

int main()
{
   char *msgin=NULL;
   http_init();
   http_send_message("message number 1", &msg_in);
   free(msgin);msgin=NULL;
   http_send_message("message number 2", &msg_in);
   free(msgin);msgin=NULL;
   http_exit();
}
```

If I call

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.133:8080/tawtaw");
```

and then

```
curl_easy_reset(curl)
```

and then

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.133:8080/tawtaw");
```

again, does the allocated memory in the first `curl_easy_setopt` get freed by `curl_easy_reset(curl)` or by the second call of `curl_easy_setopt`?

Or the memory is not freed and there is a memory leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the allocated memory in the first `curl_easy_setopt()` get freed by `curl_easy_reset(curl)` or by the second call to `curl_easy_setopt()`?

The thing is that:

1. It's an implementation detail.
2. Arising from the preceding fact, it does not/should not matter. Either one is true, proper memory management is possible in both cases.

Comment: libcurl _does_ copy the string in modern versions of libcurl, the behavior changed a couple of years ago

Still, that will not cause any leak in the example code of the question

Comment: @DanielStenberg Whoops, correct. "Strings passed to libcurl as 'char *' arguments, are copied by the library" - but it still doesn't matter when it's freed.

Comment: @DanielStenberg is it the same thing with the option `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`?? for example when we call `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, msg_out);` twice like indicated in the question

Comment: Yes (of course). Unless otherwise stated, libcurl will handle all the memory on its own.